# Converting protos/json in AWS Kinesis Firehose to Parquet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, protocol-buffers, parquet, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a long-running process which generates control signals for different entities (approx. 10k) each minute. I would like to output these control signals along with various inputs (reference points, observed values) to S3 in parquet so that we can perform some analysis on the generated control signals in an ad-hoc way. The long-running process outputs the control signals and the various inputs each minute as a proto (or JSON, proto to JSON is pretty straightforward). I am thinking of streaming the output of the long-running process into a Kinesis Firehose and using a Lambda to convert to proto/JSON to parquet. Can someone provide some pointers for lambda to convert proto/JSON to parquet files?

Comment: Hey @KunalC did you find a solution for this. I saw this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/record-format-conversion.html and want to know if you implemented this? if yes did you come across any limitations?

Comment: The feature was released by AWS after I had already implemented a lambda to convert proto to parquet using proto-parquet writer. One of the limitations of my implementation was that java's kinesis client does not guarantee order or deduplication so I had to take of that.